# Why nslookup.exe can resolved with a specified DNS server, but there isn't corresponding API in dnsapi.dll?

Tags: winapi, dns

nslookup.exe www.google.com 127.0.0.1

This command can resolve using DNS server 127.0.0.1, it's impossible to implement a full stack DNS protocol resolver in a 75.0 KB nslookup.exe, so it must have been using dnsapi.dll.

So which dll export C function can provide similar gethostbyname() with a specified DNS server in dnsapi.dll?

Comment: what makes you think you can't implement a full DNS resolver in 75KB ? the DNS protocol is not so complicated.

Comment: This is a complete DNS *server* taking up only 31KB :)

    [ljb@daishan]:/home/ljb/bin $ ls -dl `which tinydns`
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 31064 2009-03-07 08:48 /usr/bin/tinydns*

Comment: whilst the 75 kB size assertion is clearly ridiculous, `nslookup.exe` _does_ use `dnsapi.dll`.

Comment: @Leon Breedt,

perhaps it depends on libdns? Is it completely standalone without any extra libs other than stdc lib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `pExtra` parameter to the `DNSQuery` function.

Apparently the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016%28VS.85%29.aspx) is incomplete, since it says this parameter must be null.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226 for an example of its use.

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for. Why Microsoft hide that parameter?