# Why the DnsQuery return invalid DNS Record Type?

Tags: excel, vba, window, nslookup

I am trying to use DNSAPI.dll to implement a `nslookup` in VBA.

Because of the multilingual environment, I cannot implement the specified function using the method stated in the below web page:

https://www.devhut.net/vba-get-host-ip-address/

Here is my VBA code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const DnsFreeRecordList         As Long = 1
Private Const DNS_TYPE_A                As Long = &H1
Private Const DNS_TYPE_CNAME            As Long = 5
Private Const DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE    As Long = &H8
Private Const DNS_TYPE_ALL As Long = &HFF
Private Const DNS_ERROR_INVALID_NAME_CHAR As Long = &H2558
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DnsQuery Lib "dnsapi" Alias "DnsQuery_A" ( _
   ByVal lpstrName As String, _
   ByVal wType As Integer, _
   ByVal Options As Long, _
   ByVal pServers As Long, _
   ppQueryResultsSet As Long, _
   ByVal pReserved As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DnsRecordListFree Lib "dnsapi" (ByVal pDnsRecord As Long, ByVal FreeType As Long) As Long
Private Type VBDnsRecord
    pNext           As Long
    pName           As Long
    wType           As Integer
    wDataLength     As Integer
    flags           As Long
    dwTel           As Long
    dwReserved      As Long
    prt             As Long
    others(35)      As Byte
End Type
Public Function nslookup(sAddress As String) As String
    Dim pRecord     As Long
    Dim pNext       As Long
    Dim pServers    As Long
    Dim returnCode As Long
    Dim uRecord     As VBDnsRecord
    returnCode = DnsQuery(sAddress, DNS_TYPE_ALL, DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE, pServers, pRecord, 0)
    Debug.Print returnCode
    Select Case returnCode
        Case 0
             pNext = pRecord
             CopyMemory ByVal uRecord, pNext, Len(uRecord)
             Debug.Print Hex(uRecord.wType)
        Case DNS_ERROR_INVALID_NAME_CHAR
            MsgBox "DNS name contains an invalid character."
    End Select
    nslookup = sAddress
End Function
```

I used the following statement to test my function:

```
nslookup("www.ibm.com")
```

My problem is that the variable uRecord.wType always does not equal 1.

According to the following web page:

[VB6 Lookup Hostname From IP, Specifying DNS Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215203/vb6-lookup-hostname-from-ip-specifying-dns-server)

The variable uRecord.wType should contain 1.
Would you tell me why?

I am using 64-bit MS Office.