# How does one specify a specific DNS server to query using DnsQuery?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++

[DnsQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682016.aspx) doesn't have a parameter to specify the server one wants to query. On the other hand, I've seen [this sample](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226), which seems to have passed an IP in the parameter marked as "reserved and must be 0" in the MSDN documentation.

Is there some way to query a specific server (as nslookup does?) Or am I going to have to write my own DNS client (or find a library of course)?

Comment: It's formally documented with DnsQueryEx .  Look at the DNS_QUERY_REQUEST param.  It's allows you to pass a list of DNS servers.  Hmmm.... looks like this is for Windows 8 and Win8-sever only. Bummer  :(   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I would try using DnsValidateServerStatus before call to DnsQuery. There is a chance it would load necessary DNS records from the server passed to DnsValidateServerStatus into your local DNS cache, and DnsQuery would then simply reuse them. It's a hack and I never tried this, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 4th argument of DnsQuery `PVOID pExtra` accepts a `PIP4_ARRAY` containing the specific DNS servers to be queried. This is combined with the 3rd argument `DWORD Options` of DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE , in order to bypass the resolver cache.

This has worked since Windows 2000, and in Windows XP DnsQuery  calls the function
called privateNarrowToWideQuery (in dnsapi.dll) and takes the `pExtra` argument is as the PIP4_ARRAY.

The MSDN is inaccurate in this regard , resulting in this being an undocumented feature.
In older versions of the DnsQuery API Call `pExtra` used to be called `aipServers`.

Regarding the DNS  of IPV6 AAAA records, you can try the function with the second argument
`WORD wType` as `DNS_TYPE_AAAA` and the fifth argument `PDNS_RECORD *ppQueryResultsSet` as a pointer to `DNS_AAAA_DATA`. Though this still forces you to pass in IPV4 IP address array and not IPV6.

Regarding Windows Version support for the IPV6 queries see the following references

- [Domain Name Service (DNS)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726935.aspx)
- [Domain Name System Client Behavior in Windows Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727035.aspx)
- [Changes to IPv6 in Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878121.aspx)

In future Windows versions, I believe the correct way to do this for IPV6 will be using 
`DnsQueryEx` , with its first argument of `PDNS_QUERY_REQUEST pQueryRequest` which contains
a member `PDNS_ADDR_ARRAY               pDnsServerList;`, which contains member `WORD     Family;` which specifies which type of  IP address the DNS server is.

Whether DnsQuery already supports a pointer to PDNS_ADDR_ARRAY as an argument to `PVOID pExtra` or will be modified in future Windows Versions to do so, I am not sure, but you are welcome to try and see.

See [How to use the DnsQuery function to resolve host names and host addresses with Visual C++ .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831226) for sample code, as you have already discovered.

Also see the following [similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812121/why-nslookup-exe-can-resolved-with-a-specified-dns-server-but-there-isnt-corre).

Comment: Probably haven't gotten around to updating the documentation yet, the MSDN documentation for Windows CE and some of the Windows mobile stuff still mentions `aipServers`.

Answer (score -1):

There's a function for it:

```
        PCSTR       pszName = machine.c_str(); 

        DWORD       Options = NULL; 

        PVOID       pExtra = NULL; 

        PDNS_RECORD ppQueryResults; 

        PVOID       *pReserved = NULL; 



DNS_STATUS DNS_stat = DnsQuery_A(
                pszName,
                DNS_TYPE_A,
                Options,
                pExtra,
                &ppQueryResults,
                pReserved
            );
```

where pszName is the serverName.

Comment: `pszName` is the **DNS name to query** [as per the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windns/nf-windns-dnsquery_a). The question was to specify the DNS to be contacted for performing the lookup.